# Example of drag and drop design game in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm thinking about a game that a player can design his own spaceship by dragging and dropping some basic parts together then he can control it in the game.

Can any one give me a good example? I'm not so sure how to detect if a part can be placed or not in a position and its direction. And how everything can be connected together and move around as a whole rigidbody after the design is finished? Do I need to collect all the position info and create a new one or I can simply use the objects the user already created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a serialziable class linked to a specfic GameObject prefab so that the saved ship can be rebuilt at runtime. A common example is just an ID and GameObject variable.

Detect if a position is good: Make sure that it is on the 'base' object and not hitting any other colliders. Tweak to your own style ofc.

Comment: I see. So it seems that there is not general way to create a design game but just solve each condition case by case. Thanks